# Replace parts of a String, change into integer and then calculate it?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to currently mess around with columns and calculations. But I can't seem to make it work with the combinations of replace() and cast().

I got a column that is:

```
Credit History

N 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 4 5 D

N 1 2 3 1 4 5 2 3 1 2 4 3 D

N 1 3 2 1 5 2 0 0 0
```

The idea is to replace N with 0 and D with 10 so it'll look like:

```
Credit History

0 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 4 5 10

0 1 2 3 1 4 5 2 3 1 2 4 3 10

0 1 3 2 1 5 2 0 0 0
```

My plan is to add up each number so I can use the total for another calculation that i'm working on. I can get to the replace function, but I can't seem to add each number up.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Do you mean that the value of that column in a record is a string like "N 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 4 5 D"? That definitely sounds like a bad structure that's going to cause a lot of headaches. If each letter/number represents an entry of some kind, then they should be different records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table to a query that returns all the numbers from 1 to 9 and aggregate:

```
select t.CreditHistory,
       replace(replace(t.CreditHistory, 'N', '0'), 'D', '10') CreditHistory_replaced,
       coalesce(sum(n.nr * (length(t.CreditHistory) - length(replace(t.CreditHistory, n.nr, '')))), 0) + 
       (10 * (length(t.CreditHistory) - length(replace(t.CreditHistory, 'D', '')))) result
from tablename t
left join (
  select 1 nr union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
  select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
  select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
) n on t.CreditHistory like concat('%', n.nr, '%') 
group by t.CreditHistory
```

Or:

```
select t.CreditHistory,
       replace(replace(t.CreditHistory, 'N', '0'), 'D', '10') CreditHistory_replaced,
       coalesce(
         sum(n.nr * (length(t.CreditHistory) - length(replace(t.CreditHistory, case when n.nr = 10 then 'D' else n.nr end, '')))),
         0
       ) result
from tablename t
left join (
  select 1 nr union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
  select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
  select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10
) n on t.CreditHistory like concat('%', n.nr, '%') 
    or (t.CreditHistory like concat('%D%') and n.nr = 10) 
group by t.CreditHistory
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3546b548c9d2f35b5b353a646881c357).
Results:

```
> CreditHistory               | CreditHistory_replaced       | result
> :-------------------------- | :--------------------------- | -----:
> N 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 4 5 D       | 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 4 5 10       |     27
> N 1 2 3 1 4 5 2 3 1 2 4 3 D | 0 1 2 3 1 4 5 2 3 1 2 4 3 10 |     41
> N 1 3 2 1 5 2 0 0 0         | 0 1 3 2 1 5 2 0 0 0          |     14
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :D. This works and i'm still trying to figure it out. Can you explain to me what n.nr means and where it came from?

Comment: `n` is the alias of the subquery that returns the numbers 1-9 for the 1st solution or 1-10 for the 2n solution. `nr` is the name of its column. So `n.nr` represents a number 1-10. When this query is joined to the table, it is joined on the condition that `n.nr` exists inside `CreditHistory`. So the join produces for each `CreditHistory` 1 row for each `n.nr`. Then `length(t.CreditHistory) - length(..)` returns how many times `n.nr` exists inside `CreditHistory`. So this number of times is multiplied by `n.nr` and all the results are summed up.

Answer (score 0):

The below sql replaces N with 0 and D with 10 then convert values to rows. After that It sums them . you can enjoy with it :)

```
with w0 as 
(
   select replace(replace(replace(CreditHistory,'N', '0'), 'D', '10'), ' ', ',') c,
  row_number() over (order by CreditHistory) rn
  from t
), w1 as
(
  select
    rn,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(w0.c, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
  from
    (select 1 n union all
     select 2 union all select 3 union all
     select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all 
     select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all
     select 10 union all select 11) numbers INNER JOIN w0
    on CHAR_LENGTH(w0.c)
       -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(w0.c, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
  order by
    rn, n
)
select rn, sum(name) from w1
group by rn
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2wrmVEjEFWAPMvkXATj5HH/0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to add the values without looping the string. Each digit is exchanged for the number of characters with REPLACE and then the length of the strings gives the result.

```
SELECT 
    CreditHistory,
    CHAR_LENGTH(
    REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE (
    REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE (
    REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE(CreditHistory,
    'D','1111111111'),
    'N',''), ' ',''), '0',''),
    '9','111111111'),
    '8','11111111'),
    '7','1111111'),
    '6','111111'),
    '5','11111'),
    '4','1111'),
    '3','111'),
    '2','11')) as mycnt

FROM mysum;
```

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT
    -> CreditHistory,
    -> CHAR_LENGTH(
    -> REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE (
    -> REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE (
    -> REPLACE ( REPLACE ( REPLACE(CreditHistory,
    -> 'D','1111111111'),
    -> 'N',''), ' ',''), '0',''),
    -> '9','111111111'),
    -> '8','11111111'),
    -> '7','1111111'),
    -> '6','111111'),
    -> '5','11111'),
    -> '4','1111'),
    -> '3','111'),
    -> '2','11')) as mycnt
    ->
    -> FROM mysum;
+-----------------------------+-------+
| CreditHistory               | mycnt |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| N 1 0 0 1 2 3 1 4 5 D       |    27 |
| N 1 2 3 1 4 5 2 3 1 2 4 3 D |    41 |
| N 1 3 2 1 5 2 0 0 0         |    14 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```